# Interrupted line/error mark in Dynamic Data Display Chart

Tags: wpf, charts, line, dynamic-data-display

I'm using Dynamic Data Display, for line chart (in WPF). I would like to interrupt the line, and display some "Error" label in that point (or on the X axis). Can somebody help me ?

Thank you.

Comment: If you paste your code, maybe exprets can help..

Answer (score 0):

You might use a DataPoint template selector for your datapoint in lineseries, when datapoint values are matching some errors criteria you can apply a different template to the datapoint and show an error label.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I would approach this, is I would add a marker to your line graph every time this "error" occurred along your axes. If you wanted, you could make the tooltip for the marker say "error" or, even better, you could display some information about that error in the tooltip. You can use one of the markers already made in D3, or it's quite easy to create your own!

If you down load the source from [Dynamic Data Display](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/), there's many examples that have a similar requirement to yours that you could base your solution off of.